# C++ Undefined Type Error

Tags: c++

Dear all, i have two classes which are computer and floppy disk.

When i put

```
#include "FloppyDisk.h"
#include "Computer.h"
```

in main, then compiler generates error of computer undeclared

When i

```
#include "Computer.h"
#include "FloppyDisk.h"
```

in main, then compiler generates error of floppy disk undeclared.

What is the problem? 
I have check there is no cyclic dependency between the header file.

These are the implementation file for reference.

```
#include "EquipmentAttributes.h"
#include "EquipmentVisitor.h"
#include "Computer.h"

#include "BoostHeader.h"

#include <algorithm>

// =============================================
computer::computer()
 : cont()
{
}
// =============================================
void computer::add(equipment* equip)
{
 cont.push_back(equip);
}
// =============================================
void computer::remove(equipment* equip)
{
 vecIte myIte;

 myIte = std::find(cont.begin(), cont.end(), equip);
 cont.erase(myIte); 
}
// =============================================
void computer::accept(equipmentVisitor* visitor)
{
 BOOST_FOREACH(equipment* anEquip, cont)
 {
  anEquip->accept(visitor);
 }

 visitor->visitComputer(this);
}
// =============================================
computer::equipVec computer::getCont() const
{
 return cont;
}


#include "FloppyDisk.h"
#include "EquipmentAttributes.h"
#include "EquipmentVisitor.h"

// =============================================
floppyDisk::floppyDisk(const int userPrice, const std::string& userName)
 : state(new equipmentState(userPrice, userName) )
{
}
// =============================================
void floppyDisk::accept(equipmentVisitor* visitor)
{
 visitor->visitFloppyDisk(this);
}
// =============================================
floppyDisk::equipPtr floppyDisk::getState() const
{
 return state;
}
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you also post the compiler output please?

Comment: Could we see the header files, please? That's probably where the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using the same header include guard in each file, e.g.:

```
#ifndef MY_INCLUDE_GUARD
#define MY_INCLUDE_GUARD

// blah blah

#endif
```

The `MY_INCLUDE_GUARD` needs to be a unique name in each header.

Answer (score 1):

> I have check there is no cyclic
>   dependency between the header file

There may not be direct cyclic dependency between the files. However, if one of the EquipmentAttributes.h or EquipmentVisitor.h includes either computer.h or floppy.h you create a cyclic depenedcy involving three files. In such a case, you get the undefined type compiler error.